# mongodb add values of keys between two objects

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a matchmaking algo comparing two objects with each other.
In detail I have to substract each key of the objects, resulting into an output object with the subtracted values. However the tricky part is that the keys might not be defined in one of the objects.

The objects e.g. can look like this:

```
{
  userMDs: {
    md1: 0.5,
    md2: 0.5,
    md3: 1,
    md7: -0.5,
    md8: 0.5,
    md9: 1,
    md13: -0.5,
    md14: 0.5,
    md15: 1,
    md19: -0.5,
    md20: -1,
    md21: 1,
    md25: -0.5,
    md26: 1
  },
    matchMDs: {
    md1: 0.5,
    md2: 0.5,
    md3: 1,
    md7: -0.5,
    md15: 1,
    md19: -0.5,
    md20: -1,
    md21: 1,
    md25: -0.5,
    md26: 1
  },
}
```

Identifying which keys are matching, I do this logic:

```
 {
    $addFields: {
      commonKeys: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$userMDs" },
          as: "userMD",
          cond: { $in: ["$$userMD.k", { $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$matchMDs" }, as: "matchMD", in: "$$matchMD.k" } }] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

This results into a new object called "commonKeys", containing the matching keys.
I am now having troubles doing the substraction for the values of the keys that are existing in both objects.

Is there a way to look over each key of the commonKeys and access both the other objects for the substraction?

Thanks in advance for any hint...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the behaviour you want, here are the 2 versions of the aggregation.

## Ignore missing keys, subtract only existing

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      commonKeys: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$userMDs"
          },
          as: "userMD",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$userMD.k",
              {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    $objectToArray: "$matchMDs"
                  },
                  as: "matchMD",
                  in: "$$matchMD.k"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      subtracted: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$commonKeys",
            as: "common",
            in: {
              k: "$$common.k",
              v: {
                $round: [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      "$$common.v",
                      {
                        $ifNull: [
                          {
                            $arrayElemAt: [
                              {
                                $map: {
                                  input: {
                                    $filter: {
                                      input: {
                                        $objectToArray: "$matchMDs"
                                      },
                                      as: "item",
                                      cond: {
                                        $eq: [
                                          "$$item.k",
                                          "$$common.k"
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  as: "item",
                                  in: "$$item.v"
                                }
                              },
                              0
                            ]
                          },
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  1
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      difference: "$subtracted"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P0Y2FDLYKYm) where you can test this aggregation to see that it works.

## Subtract values even of missing keys

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      userMDsArr: {
        $objectToArray: "$userMDs"
      },
      matchMDsArr: {
        $objectToArray: "$matchMDs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      subtracted: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$userMDsArr",
            as: "userMD",
            in: {
              k: "$$userMD.k",
              v: {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    matchMD: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$matchMDsArr",
                            as: "matchMD",
                            cond: {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$matchMD.k",
                                "$$userMD.k"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    
                  },
                  in: {
                    $round: [
                      {
                        $subtract: [
                          "$$userMD.v",
                          {
                            $ifNull: [
                              "$$matchMD.v",
                              0
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      1
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      subtracted: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tKIrNJc6qyy) where you can test this aggregation to see that it works.